# Set focus to another Control

Tags: c#

i want to set focus from one textbox1 to another textbox2 while i am pressing ENTER key in textbox1 in C# windows application(c# 2005)

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to set the **KeyPreview** property of the Form set to **true**. Then you will have to override the form's OnKeyDown method and make a case like:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
      Control ctlNext = this.GetNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true);
      ctlNext.Focus();
}
else
{
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Mind you that this code will work for every control on the form, and move the focus to the next one. If you just want this code to work for the textboxes you could add a check like:

```
if(this.ActiveControl is TextBox)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Remember to set e.SuppressKeyPress = true there somewhere too, or the Enter keypress will stil register to other controls (eg the form's AcceptButton).

Answer (score 1):

add this to your form

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Control NextControl = this.GetNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true);
                while (!NextControl.TabStop || !NextControl.Enabled || !NextControl.Visible)
                {
                    NextControl=this.GetNextControl(NextControl, true);
                }
                NextControl.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) or [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event of `textbox1` and then call `textbox2.Focus()`.